# Running PySpark using Cronjob (crontab) not working

Tags: python, pyspark, cron

I'm trying to submit my pyspark code through cron job. When I run manually, its working fine. Through cron its not working.

Here is the project structure I have:

```
my-project
|
|--src
|----jobs
|------execute_metrics.py
|----utils
|------get_spark_session.py
```

The main code lies in `execute_metrics.py` from `src/jobs`. I'm using `get_spark_session.py`
 in `execute_metrics.py` using `from src.utils import get_spark_session`.

I created a shell script `execute_metric.sh` with below content for executing the cron job

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=<included entire path here>
spark-submit <included required options> src/jobs/execute_metrics.py
```

```
my-project
|
|--src
|----jobs
|------execute_metrics.py
|----utils
|------get_spark_session.py
|--execute_metric.sh
```

When I run this shell script using `./execute_metric.sh`, I'm able to see the results.

Now, I need this to run the job every minute. So, I created a cron file with below content and copied in the same directory

`* * * * * ./execute_metric.sh > execute_metric_log.log`

```
my-project
|
|--src
|----jobs
|------execute_metrics.py
|----utils
|------get_spark_session.py
|--execute_metric.sh
|--execute_cron.crontab
```

This cron is running for every minute, but giving me the error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`

Can someone please tell me what went wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed by adding a `main.py` file in the project directory and changed my cron to execute `main.py`. The project structure now looks like:

```
my-project
|
|--src
|----jobs
|------execute_metrics.py
|----utils
|------get_spark_session.py
|--execute_metric.sh
|--execute_cron.crontab
|--main.py
```

In `main.py`, I'm invoking the functions of `execute_metrics.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Your module directories are not getting into the python path. Try one of the following:

Explicitly set the `PYTHONPATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=<included entire path here>
PYTHONPATH=somewhere/my-project/src
spark-submit <included required options> src/jobs/execute_metrics.py
```

Invoke the spark shell from your project directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=<included entire path here>
cd somewhere/my-project/src
spark-submit <included required options> execute_metrics.py
```